# Wordpress .htaccess rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress installed. I want to customize permalink as following:

```
Category: http://my-domain/{category-name}/
Post: http://my-domain/{category-name}/{postname}/
Post with params: http://my-domain/{category-name}/{postname}/{param1}/
Post with params: http://my-domain/{category-name}/{postname}/{param1}/{param2}/
```

Can I do only use .htaccess?
Thanks!

P.S: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The permalink customization is done through the admin panel. WordPress parses the URL in PHP. Maybe you could do some hacky things with `.htaccess`, but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Admin panel can not pass params:
Ex: http://my-domain/{category-name}/{post-name}/{param-name}/
Then, in my code use $_REQUEST['param-name']

Answer (score 1):

In the admin dashboard, customize the permanent links to

```
http://my-domain/%category%/%postname%/
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But, how to do with post parameters?
Ex: http://my-domain/{category}/{postname}/{param}/
And, in my code use $_REQUEST['param']

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress you can do this through backend. Go to `Settings-->Permalinks-->Custom Structure` and insert:

`%category%/%postname%`

[You can refer here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

If you wish to use other subfolders you need to create .htaccess file (if you are using Apache) in your root folder and use url rewrite like this:

`RedirectMatch 301 /old-directory/(.*) /new-directory/`

Be sure mod_rewrite Apache module is enabled.